AccessDeniedException lambdaRole not authorized to perform bedrock:GetPrompt
So I have created a prompt in bedrock and I want to get this prompt in my lambda function.
But I keep getting the error
User: arn:aws:sts::xxxxx:assumed-role/pumppalLambdaRole3da0a829-staging/BedrockSchedule-staging is not authorized to perform: bedrock:GetPrompt

I have added these custom policies to my lambda
[
  {
    "Action": [
      "bedrock:GetPrompt",
      "bedrock:ListPrompts",
      "bedrock:InvokeModel",
      "bedrock:ListFoundationModels"
    ],
    "Resource": ["*"]
  },
  {
    "Action": ["s3:*"],
    "Resource": ["*"]
  }
]

I also added the AmazonBedrockFullAccess AWS Managed policy to my lambda role.
I have double checked that these policies are attached to my lambda role. Beside this I have no idea what could be the problem.
Here is the full stacktrace
{
    "errorType": "AccessDeniedException",
    "errorMessage": "User: arn:aws:sts::xxxxxx:assumed-role/pumppalLambdaRole3da0a829-staging/BedrockSchedule-staging is not authorized to perform: bedrock:GetPrompt",
    "name": "AccessDeniedException",
    "$fault": "client",
    "$metadata": {
        "httpStatusCode": 403,
        "requestId": "f9fb5346-3273-4584-b453-655b4539a1ba",
        "attempts": 1,
        "totalRetryDelay": 0
    },
    "stack": [
        "AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:sts::xxxxxx:assumed-role/pumppalLambdaRole3da0a829-staging/BedrockSchedule-staging is not authorized to perform: bedrock:GetPrompt",
        "    at de_AccessDeniedExceptionRes (/var/task/node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-sdk+client-bedrock-agent@3.635.0/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-bedrock-agent/dist-cjs/index.js:3085:21)",
        "    at de_CommandError (/var/task/node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-sdk+client-bedrock-agent@3.635.0/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-bedrock-agent/dist-cjs/index.js:3049:19)",
        "    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)",
        "    at async /var/task/node_modules/.pnpm/@smithy+middleware-serde@3.0.3/node_modules/@smithy/middleware-serde/dist-cjs/index.js:35:20",
        "    at async /var/task/node_modules/.pnpm/@smithy+core@2.4.0/node_modules/@smithy/core/dist-cjs/index.js:165:18",
        "    at async /var/task/node_modules/.pnpm/@smithy+middleware-retry@3.0.15/node_modules/@smithy/middleware-retry/dist-cjs/index.js:320:38",
        "    at async /var/task/node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-sdk+middleware-logger@3.609.0/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-logger/dist-cjs/index.js:34:22",
        "    at async getPrompt (file:///var/task/index.js:43:20)",
        "    at async Runtime.handler (file:///var/task/index.js:57:26)"
    ]
}

All help is greatly appreciated!

If you've attached the built-in AmazonBedrockFullAccess policy then I suggest removing your inline policy to ensure no conflict between the two.
